# Subset dataframe based on partial string match in columns names and grouping variable from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have this dataframe :

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ZDR_1100 = c(4.35257768630981, 4.38319635391235, 
3.45875406265259, 2.89925289154053, 2.60276365280151, 2.4752631187439, 
5.74293756484985, 5.42184591293335, 4.83091688156128, 5.24747276306152, 
5.70190763473511, 4.87028217315674, 5.17230653762817, 5.08260774612427, 
4.81965684890747, 4.66756105422974, 5.0771336555481, 4.72221279144287, 
4.35368251800537, 4.04652738571167, 3.92501735687256, 3.25289344787598, 
4.9099588394165, 3.61346507072449, 2.86027479171753, 2.80301856994629, 
3.61852407455444, 3.21489191055298, 2.71174764633179, 2.27379631996155, 
2.77058076858521, 2.29727435112, 3.03683042526245, 2.75577831268311, 
2.73691439628601, 3.91593050956726, 3.26109004020691, 3.33541226387024, 
4.11713981628418, 3.07647657394409, 3.66882586479187, 2.18893122673035, 
2.80019092559814, 4.1174144744873, 5.18397521972656, 4.1416130065918, 
4.42369508743286, 4.97338628768921, 4.36334180831909, 4.89630126953125
), ZDR_1500 = c(4.05539798736572, 3.99731683731079, 4.29577016830444, 
4.29434013366699, 4.22943830490112, 2.84611749649048, 5.12784099578857, 
5.19554948806763, 4.93876266479492, 4.51952648162842, 4.97228956222534, 
5.0228009223938, 5.08884048461914, 5.03080415725708, 5.03219699859619, 
5.01467800140381, 4.85552167892456, 4.78733777999878, 4.83317470550537, 
4.88904666900635, 4.84485006332397, 5.41747522354126, 4.94736289978027, 
5.31124830245972, 3.77076578140259, 4.08486318588257, 4.30972814559937, 
4.73209619522095, 4.50979518890381, 3.81461977958679, 3.18703866004944, 
3.40575408935547, 3.64623713493347, 3.77229022979736, 3.37799882888794, 
3.28994154930115, 4.03835964202881, 3.9747474193573, 4.79940032958984, 
4.484375, 4.92587184906006, 4.116455078125, 5.18043088912964, 
5.18948936462402, 4.48871660232544, 5.25668001174927, 5.67960834503174, 
5.81076383590698, 4.27840900421143, 5.28551244735718), ZDR_1700 = c(3.7973484992981, 
4.12657833099365, 3.89046716690063, 5.2465181350708, 4.35845947265625, 
3.41382575035095, 4.20833301544189, 3.97159099578857, 4.35732316970825, 
3.68813133239746, 3.95761179924011, 4.1755051612854, 4.13618850708008, 
4.00023651123047, 4.55681800842285, 4.72253799438477, 4.10646867752075, 
4.32711029052734, 3.95815277099609, 4.64330816268921, 4.50062656402588, 
6.04105472564697, 5.29774188995361, 4.74261569976807, 3.73241329193115, 
3.80834794044495, 4.02044010162354, 5.17622518539429, 5.25316619873047, 
5.15032052993774, 3.79120516777039, 5.37545108795166, 4.06849765777588, 
5.01755523681641, 4.97695732116699, 3.17582082748413, 4.58097314834595, 
4.08080816268921, 4.71180534362793, 5.26325750350952, 4.94696950912476, 
5.46780300140381, 5.41761350631714, 5.43402767181396, 4.04316711425781, 
5.16792917251587, 5.98263883590698, 5.85290384292603, 4.38636350631714, 
5.50983381271362), ZDR_1900 = c(2.35795450210571, 2.60195708274841, 
2.23137617111206, 3.25504088401794, 2.42285346984863, 2.53882575035095, 
2.38636350631714, 2.41761350631714, 2.58838367462158, 2.0252525806427, 
2.13320708274841, 2.43023991584778, 2.35020399093628, 2.32220649719238, 
3.07386374473572, 3.09059357643127, 2.2882866859436, 2.90151524543762, 
2.02462100982666, 2.58933091163635, 2.83869481086731, 3.87060022354126, 
3.49376463890076, 3.06404423713684, 2.2720959186554, 2.66724944114685, 
2.39259910583496, 3.11372518539429, 3.33271193504333, 3.45145678520203, 
3.01933026313782, 3.6502525806427, 2.60321974754333, 3.16433572769165, 
3.30366158485413, 2.38699507713318, 2.89157938957214, 2.46622467041016, 
2.90972208976746, 3.40530323982239, 2.9848484992981, 3.67803025245667, 
3.39583325386047, 3.76452016830444, 3.36797785758972, 3.20107316970825, 
3.95707058906555, 3.83964657783508, 3.16856074333191, 3.62820506095886
), DateHour = structure(c(1403870400, 1403870400, 1403874000, 
1403874000, 1403874000, 1403874000, 1404291600, 1404291600, 1404291600, 
1404295200, 1404295200, 1404295200, 1404295200, 1404295200, 1404295200, 
1404295200, 1404298800, 1404298800, 1404298800, 1404298800, 1404298800, 
1404298800, 1404298800, 1404298800, 1404298800, 1404298800, 1404302400, 
1404302400, 1404302400, 1404302400, 1404302400, 1404302400, 1404302400, 
1404302400, 1404302400, 1404306000, 1404900000, 1404900000, 1404903600, 
1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600, 
1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600, 1404903600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "BST"), dBZ_1100 = c(13.0533227920532, 7.64343404769897, 
7.55345487594604, -4.43169403076172, -3.67185807228088, 11.5491628646851, 
0.099544070661068, 0.4189692735672, 0.603640377521515, 23.5292472839355, 
0.876559674739838, 1.21858334541321, 30.2494983673096, 14.5061016082764, 
18.0746917724609, 27.3994846343994, -1.52240204811096, -1.09185898303986, 
-1.03976023197174, -1.62606370449066, -2.67170429229736, -1.10380160808563, 
-2.05051803588867, 20.9851169586182, -2.37661457061768, -1.93547701835632, 
6.43747711181641, -2.41227865219116, -2.70366144180298, -2.48516869544983, 
-2.79775285720825, 13.0787258148193, 15.7631845474243, -3.58373808860779, 
-3.7710235118866, -5.28177785873413, 4.80499362945557, -5.53175926208496, 
-5.44945955276489, 26.6477088928223, -5.62642860412598, -5.87120008468628, 
23.9094676971436, -4.23756217956543, 12.2331943511963, 25.1120662689209, 
18.5673885345459, 12.2040147781372, 7.41675806045532, -2.54055261611938
), dBZ_1300 = c(-2.67366552352905, 7.77584457397461, 8.31201171875, 
-2.39615082740784, -2.32896304130554, 11.5863180160522, -0.55341362953186, 
-0.407999604940414, -0.262424468994141, 23.5262928009033, -0.0324550457298756, 
0.474246680736542, 30.2489414215088, 0.780959784984589, 18.0856132507324, 
27.3387641906738, -0.240789473056793, 0.717265188694, 0.605446577072144, 
0.704368650913239, 0.164543613791466, 0.77489823102951, 0.331973552703857, 
21.0028533935547, -0.180411159992218, 0.258325219154358, -0.0808558687567711, 
-0.889077544212341, -0.505846858024597, -0.51402360200882, -1.10388088226318, 
-1.98930990695953, 15.812557220459, -3.32990503311157, -3.97293877601624, 
-5.85209321975708, -4.60489797592163, -3.88196325302124, -3.51285600662231, 
-3.12323451042175, -1.08725774288177, -2.94287610054016, 23.8969707489014, 
-1.1184207201004, 12.4989643096924, 25.1149730682373, 18.5668697357178, 
12.2572259902954, 12.3675403594971, -1.04065454006195), dBZ_1500 = c(-4.28500127792358, 
12.9901723861694, 2.06604433059692, -1.57755088806152, -1.75198185443878, 
-3.62787580490112, 5.35268545150757, -1.93759298324585, -1.80987310409546, 
-2.52091956138611, -1.64943778514862, -1.19708693027496, -0.831158876419067, 
-0.216383308172226, 0.340205609798431, -0.256466269493103, -0.444619059562683, 
0.721450626850128, 0.758045017719269, 1.13218820095062, 0.68219405412674, 
1.49298453330994, 0.910578906536102, 3.61230778694153, 0.354260563850403, 
0.874321281909943, 0.799070477485657, 0.235398530960083, 0.589350581169128, 
0.396219164133072, -0.214650198817253, -0.907533407211304, 3.55952072143555, 
-2.41985082626343, -3.29412865638733, -5.65235042572021, -4.29837226867676, 
22.5924263000488, -2.97164034843445, -2.4972562789917, 1.25916743278503, 
-0.887719213962555, -0.710097908973694, 0.101506605744362, 2.82986521720886, 
0.467019379138947, -0.400585263967514, -0.631934225559235, 10.9010696411133, 
-0.250145018100739), dBZ_1700 = c(10.837306022644, 12.9630470275879, 
1.87502336502075, -1.21396267414093, 17.7504043579102, -2.91416573524475, 
4.92221689224243, -5.2473783493042, -4.87473154067993, -5.43080997467041, 
-5.38822364807129, -4.80557441711426, -4.02333736419678, -2.37155342102051, 
-1.80130207538605, -2.37811756134033, -1.98119735717773, -0.443167269229889, 
-0.690286755561829, 0.28509646654129, 0.07586370408535, 0.980131149291992, 
0.100692130625248, 0.801274061203003, -0.719405651092529, 0.150555282831192, 
0.33085173368454, -0.0484558753669262, 0.30492952466011, 0.507157564163208, 
-0.0625267326831818, -0.669517993927002, 3.66127991676331, -1.70856142044067, 
-2.24174809455872, -4.66836786270142, -4.51424169540405, 22.5914363861084, 
-3.65310525894165, -2.74041390419006, 1.28378868103027, -0.614114344120026, 
-0.462400168180466, 0.518114268779755, 2.79723906517029, 0.145962208509445, 
0.0638472363352776, -0.199055701494217, 10.9353580474854, 0.133241817355156
), dBZ_1900 = c(10.8179788589478, 12.9099559783936, -4.19234132766724, 
-3.37985777854919, 17.7317123413086, -4.92272853851318, 4.68751430511475, 
-8.35651302337646, -7.83676433563232, -8.42444610595703, -8.38865756988525, 
-8.38711547851562, -7.99302959442139, -6.67590522766113, -6.3273229598999, 
-6.16515874862671, -5.95890760421753, -4.4605278968811, -4.71776866912842, 
-3.55448389053345, -3.85400032997131, -2.79580211639404, -3.54037094116211, 
-2.41316890716553, -4.26820516586304, -3.08155393600464, -2.20567870140076, 
-1.97367656230927, -2.16329312324524, -1.87266504764557, -2.31724095344543, 
-2.30043697357178, 2.41777086257935, -3.01146125793457, -3.31047129631042, 
-5.67029666900635, -6.82329511642456, 22.58713722229, -6.48832941055298, 
-5.21997308731079, -1.03424751758575, -2.463219165802, -2.97928643226624, 
-1.87164890766144, -1.48916876316071, -1.68843734264374, -1.81144285202026, 
-2.00282979011536, -2.46254062652588, -1.88401103019714), RhoHV_1100 = c(0.695769369602203, 
0.634697616100311, 0.605578362941742, 0.576942324638367, 0.579119384288788, 
0.481261223554611, 0.752298891544342, 0.772573888301849, 0.780646860599518, 
0.743842601776123, 0.784943461418152, 0.785655856132507, 0.774651944637299, 
0.743582248687744, 0.739660739898682, 0.740167438983917, 0.693434059619904, 
0.701235830783844, 0.692198991775513, 0.670656859874725, 0.632660686969757, 
0.64829033613205, 0.655531942844391, 0.66856050491333, 0.614904344081879, 
0.646230638027191, 0.632404029369354, 0.626040458679199, 0.618177056312561, 
0.626113474369049, 0.613851189613342, 0.610502958297729, 0.607620060443878, 
0.603256404399872, 0.595137417316437, 0.541356325149536, 0.515563488006592, 
0.532689690589905, 0.548793315887451, 0.575978755950928, 0.534284949302673, 
0.505646705627441, 0.525772094726562, 0.594364762306213, 0.680047452449799, 
0.667022585868835, 0.666417002677917, 0.66333943605423, 0.639558911323547, 
0.696662366390228), RhoHV_1300 = c(0.670131623744965, 0.736148655414581, 
0.708418011665344, 0.674268782138824, 0.661670506000519, 0.569565296173096, 
0.746592581272125, 0.759550988674164, 0.765773892402649, 0.741412162780762, 
0.773507416248322, 0.789483606815338, 0.768384516239166, 0.787292659282684, 
0.748403012752533, 0.776650905609131, 0.766514897346497, 0.785999417304993, 
0.774159908294678, 0.761422097682953, 0.735611915588379, 0.748986840248108, 
0.75470107793808, 0.76655250787735, 0.724855244159698, 0.735365331172943, 
0.71841698884964, 0.706667006015778, 0.70792430639267, 0.702304720878601, 
0.681767761707306, 0.659574151039124, 0.660505712032318, 0.634253084659576, 
0.608951330184937, 0.539145231246948, 0.607953369617462, 0.633927285671234, 
0.662352681159973, 0.66534686088562, 0.660534501075745, 0.631454348564148, 
0.647155344486237, 0.701039612293243, 0.754760682582855, 0.735258221626282, 
0.724355280399323, 0.723224818706512, 0.716908574104309, 0.750032663345337
), RhoHV_1500 = c(0.596582531929016, 0.714597046375275, 0.725619792938232, 
0.704416930675507, 0.68214750289917, 0.601039111614227, 0.692344605922699, 
0.68582946062088, 0.696639716625214, 0.681377768516541, 0.692142248153687, 
0.70999276638031, 0.709114193916321, 0.752301752567291, 0.719752788543701, 
0.748071610927582, 0.745342671871185, 0.776340842247009, 0.773041367530823, 
0.79331761598587, 0.767857432365417, 0.791779637336731, 0.786773324012756, 
0.784988224506378, 0.76576167345047, 0.778463661670685, 0.778952598571777, 
0.75350546836853, 0.769649684429169, 0.743348002433777, 0.730197072029114, 
0.709957242012024, 0.703209340572357, 0.675722062587738, 0.641082227230072, 
0.555113196372986, 0.619501769542694, 0.655060887336731, 0.688604474067688, 
0.7029749751091, 0.710927128791809, 0.698081195354462, 0.731070518493652, 
0.761828899383545, 0.795517444610596, 0.791573405265808, 0.775348961353302, 
0.764878928661346, 0.754271507263184, 0.773677408695221), RhoHV_1700 = c(0.486187964677811, 
0.650815069675446, 0.718304514884949, 0.722578883171082, 0.721846878528595, 
0.648686051368713, 0.581354260444641, 0.565854430198669, 0.583405613899231, 
0.573630928993225, 0.581930875778198, 0.608589828014374, 0.599293172359467, 
0.648198366165161, 0.62637585401535, 0.6468346118927, 0.649178087711334, 
0.713888585567474, 0.700619399547577, 0.736356854438782, 0.728652775287628, 
0.760977864265442, 0.750246524810791, 0.741621255874634, 0.708053827285767, 
0.749155044555664, 0.754545032978058, 0.753751397132874, 0.75898951292038, 
0.770309269428253, 0.766107976436615, 0.739911794662476, 0.748734951019287, 
0.722147524356842, 0.693309783935547, 0.602664411067963, 0.622021615505219, 
0.644728481769562, 0.644144654273987, 0.704655408859253, 0.708551228046417, 
0.73676985502243, 0.75530993938446, 0.794319212436676, 0.800550878047943, 
0.788301289081573, 0.798223853111267, 0.787411212921143, 0.787127912044525, 
0.802554249763489), RhoHV_1900 = c(0.32033434510231, 0.386393845081329, 
0.450942665338516, 0.460095554590225, 0.471756875514984, 0.418326050043106, 
0.345010936260223, 0.337490797042847, 0.346625626087189, 0.335166066884995, 
0.343759655952454, 0.35417827963829, 0.35727322101593, 0.379776865243912, 
0.383851617574692, 0.384544938802719, 0.381322026252747, 0.433120995759964, 
0.421341806650162, 0.452778369188309, 0.447516679763794, 0.472410887479782, 
0.464259892702103, 0.456166714429855, 0.431501120328903, 0.470262318849564, 
0.480388075113297, 0.491935670375824, 0.484025567770004, 0.499174386262894, 
0.503118276596069, 0.491303026676178, 0.493557065725327, 0.488636642694473, 
0.476412206888199, 0.418399572372437, 0.3878513276577, 0.400128155946732, 
0.38995948433876, 0.44673752784729, 0.440457582473755, 0.468618005514145, 
0.477443546056747, 0.515209496021271, 0.527496039867401, 0.519628286361694, 
0.525355994701385, 0.519922733306885, 0.511509418487549, 0.527509689331055
), PhiDP_1100 = c(-61.9122848510742, -61.7745628356934, -62.5470237731934, 
-61.9537925720215, -63.0958061218262, -63.1592826843262, -64.768684387207, 
-65.8956146240234, -65.7770767211914, -66.3598327636719, -65.5749588012695, 
-64.7086029052734, -63.9156761169434, -65.8752365112305, -61.4799957275391, 
-66.3929061889648, -65.2737655639648, -65.3992233276367, -64.8776168823242, 
-65.5307922363281, -66.1405029296875, -66.1186981201172, -64.4617080688477, 
-66.0745468139648, -63.3511924743652, -64.758659362793, -63.9585113525391, 
-63.9376182556152, -62.9862365722656, -61.2109375, -61.9911231994629, 
-62.9701118469238, -57.2107315063477, -62.6806488037109, -60.9584350585938, 
-64.2847747802734, -69.3955688476562, -67.1649398803711, -72.5553131103516, 
-70.874153137207, -71.3225173950195, -71.7393798828125, -66.9394226074219, 
-70.9865951538086, -71.9435195922852, -73.9155120849609, -71.0122528076172, 
-68.9823150634766, -69.0143356323242, -70.2533721923828), PhiDP_1300 = c(-61.2983818054199, 
-59.5536231994629, -60.1214485168457, -61.53076171875, -61.5398178100586, 
-61.4159698486328, -66.5602340698242, -67.2551040649414, -67.9956512451172, 
-69.0430145263672, -67.3178253173828, -67.2887954711914, -66.319206237793, 
-66.3491668701172, -67.5580596923828, -68.7653579711914, -66.3744659423828, 
-65.4024810791016, -65.932746887207, -67.391731262207, -66.429328918457, 
-67.6350326538086, -66.0151824951172, -67.1428451538086, -64.3616333007812, 
-65.979362487793, -64.8137435913086, -64.5170440673828, -64.243782043457, 
-62.6859931945801, -63.1390266418457, -63.4074935913086, -58.0757293701172, 
-64.2588348388672, -63.5895347595215, -65.3224411010742, -68.3536071777344, 
-68.5899810791016, -71.0225524902344, -73.0878448486328, -70.2164840698242, 
-72.8035354614258, -65.6377868652344, -70.30078125, -68.3574676513672, 
-73.8592910766602, -70.5053253173828, -68.2069854736328, -74.0192184448242, 
-70.2041015625), PhiDP_1500 = c(-60.6405372619629, -58.6443519592285, 
-60.0927734375, -61.2959442138672, -60.5599708557129, -59.3951950073242, 
-65.25146484375, -67.3581771850586, -69.7190170288086, -69.256706237793, 
-68.7841796875, -67.982063293457, -68.5673370361328, -67.6735610961914, 
-71.1172714233398, -67.3188934326172, -66.8971939086914, -65.9585876464844, 
-66.1747589111328, -67.8579940795898, -65.9854431152344, -68.0561981201172, 
-67.2381057739258, -68.1099090576172, -65.8218612670898, -66.03271484375, 
-65.5215759277344, -65.2512435913086, -64.6067123413086, -63.2652702331543, 
-65.13671875, -63.5515785217285, -61.3423309326172, -64.6402282714844, 
-65.5644073486328, -66.6690368652344, -68.3957748413086, -70.0650329589844, 
-71.827507019043, -73.3511657714844, -71.4126892089844, -72.1071548461914, 
-72.135124206543, -70.5961456298828, -68.6991729736328, -71.783561706543, 
-71.0409240722656, -69.6282424926758, -75.4569854736328, -70.0989837646484
), PhiDP_1700 = c(-51.1749839782715, -59.6084861755371, -59.7052536010742, 
-58.90625, -60.1851005554199, -60.0763473510742, -66.7356185913086, 
-70.8864517211914, -71.6779174804688, -69.5503387451172, -71.8616790771484, 
-70.1460418701172, -69.8983459472656, -69.8601760864258, -70.0759048461914, 
-66.915397644043, -65.2232818603516, -65.2068557739258, -67.0862884521484, 
-68.1502990722656, -66.1772003173828, -67.1519927978516, -66.1967315673828, 
-67.4533920288086, -67.6495895385742, -66.5061264038086, -66.4084701538086, 
-66.236686706543, -65.9770050048828, -65.2787628173828, -65.4829559326172, 
-64.9098892211914, -64.1135482788086, -66.9513473510742, -67.1843948364258, 
-66.358757019043, -69.9205474853516, -72.3854751586914, -71.7143096923828, 
-71.7831192016602, -73.2124481201172, -71.3520965576172, -70.479850769043, 
-70.474967956543, -67.2829360961914, -72.3362045288086, -71.4857025146484, 
-70.3040618896484, -75.224609375, -69.7314453125), PhiDP_1900 = c(-29.9973373413086, 
-39.90234375, -40.9805564880371, -38.3997688293457, -40.5881576538086, 
-40.3622169494629, -44.0731544494629, -48.3065528869629, -48.6159477233887, 
-45.9583625793457, -49.5094985961914, -46.9615592956543, -47.0467872619629, 
-47.2682876586914, -43.6474609375, -44.5272560119629, -43.0548629760742, 
-43.7588768005371, -45.0164222717285, -45.6809310913086, -44.2604789733887, 
-44.5747528076172, -43.8844985961914, -44.9214324951172, -45.7848014831543, 
-44.3763313293457, -44.5210418701172, -44.5969467163086, -43.8725166320801, 
-43.6669921875, -43.9790458679199, -43.6536750793457, -43.6217155456543, 
-45.0266342163086, -44.1490592956543, -44.1583824157715, -45.9690170288086, 
-48.3447265625, -48.2488479614258, -46.4852638244629, -49.6590919494629, 
-47.4032325744629, -47.1102638244629, -47.1959342956543, -46.4235649108887, 
-48.0917091369629, -46.9216079711914, -47.1462173461914, -46.3525390625, 
-46.2766304016113), SQI_1100 = c(0.290561854839325, 0.218571126461029, 
0.232207491993904, 0.18707911670208, 0.190372481942177, 0.164036199450493, 
0.146264731884003, 0.141761362552643, 0.172948241233826, 0.169591754674911, 
0.146033257246017, 0.158459588885307, 0.146380469202995, 0.140635520219803, 
0.164372891187668, 0.165214642882347, 0.137994527816772, 0.134617000818253, 
0.138320699334145, 0.138005048036575, 0.147095963358879, 0.135953277349472, 
0.136353120207787, 0.156071126461029, 0.132944032549858, 0.159480214118958, 
0.149473905563354, 0.148305967450142, 0.149747475981712, 0.140340909361839, 
0.158712118864059, 0.159048825502396, 0.158985689282417, 0.13235479593277, 
0.150094702839851, 0.128472223877907, 0.186542510986328, 0.179598063230515, 
0.173348069190979, 0.179082483053207, 0.165235683321953, 0.1692024320364, 
0.163836270570755, 0.177735686302185, 0.205502942204475, 0.239025667309761, 
0.221401512622833, 0.204366579651833, 0.213489055633545, 0.205808073282242
), SQI_1300 = c(0.309185594320297, 0.297064393758774, 0.301231056451797, 
0.258522719144821, 0.24876894056797, 0.235795453190804, 0.195928022265434, 
0.181534096598625, 0.211458340287209, 0.21325758099556, 0.188541665673256, 
0.206439390778542, 0.203409090638161, 0.180303037166595, 0.201515153050423, 
0.209090903401375, 0.174715906381607, 0.166287884116173, 0.191666662693024, 
0.175568178296089, 0.211174234747887, 0.176988631486893, 0.183806821703911, 
0.220359846949577, 0.18229167163372, 0.193465903401375, 0.191666662693024, 
0.183238640427589, 0.187310606241226, 0.193371221423149, 0.17859847843647, 
0.181250005960464, 0.181818187236786, 0.17339015007019, 0.179450750350952, 
0.160984843969345, 0.238731056451797, 0.238731056451797, 0.218276515603065, 
0.222537875175476, 0.226893931627274, 0.226231068372726, 0.212026506662369, 
0.213825762271881, 0.227178037166595, 0.245549246668816, 0.228030309081078, 
0.219412878155708, 0.235795453190804, 0.1875), SQI_1500 = c(0.291824489831924, 
0.312026500701904, 0.312973469495773, 0.318813115358353, 0.293402761220932, 
0.273674249649048, 0.222064390778542, 0.207228541374207, 0.225852265954018, 
0.211805552244186, 0.207544192671776, 0.224431827664375, 0.216856062412262, 
0.210858583450317, 0.217803031206131, 0.225694432854652, 0.204387620091438, 
0.198863640427589, 0.226010099053383, 0.221906572580338, 0.244949489831924, 
0.234375, 0.232796713709831, 0.264046728610992, 0.228693187236786, 
0.229955807328224, 0.222853541374207, 0.214172974228859, 0.221275255084038, 
0.231376260519028, 0.215277776122093, 0.218434348702431, 0.215909093618393, 
0.216382578015327, 0.205018937587738, 0.179608583450317, 0.272569447755814, 
0.272253781557083, 0.246369943022728, 0.267361104488373, 0.282828271389008, 
0.27509468793869, 0.261521458625793, 0.26231062412262, 0.243529051542282, 
0.25615531206131, 0.228219702839851, 0.236584588885307, 0.23926767706871, 
0.199179291725159), SQI_1700 = c(0.258207082748413, 0.283143937587738, 
0.329545438289642, 0.347222208976746, 0.351641416549683, 0.287878781557083, 
0.231060609221458, 0.204861104488373, 0.242424234747887, 0.220328271389008, 
0.221275255084038, 0.235795453190804, 0.228219702839851, 0.221275255084038, 
0.228219702839851, 0.234217166900635, 0.221906557679176, 0.220643937587738, 
0.253472208976746, 0.244633838534355, 0.282828271389008, 0.250946968793869, 
0.248421713709831, 0.30145201086998, 0.25, 0.261679291725159, 
0.255997478961945, 0.252525240182877, 0.238320708274841, 0.241792932152748, 
0.222853541374207, 0.231691911816597, 0.256628781557083, 0.241477265954018, 
0.236742421984673, 0.222222223877907, 0.298611104488373, 0.309659093618393, 
0.254419207572937, 0.30334597826004, 0.305555552244186, 0.320075750350952, 
0.320707082748413, 0.336174249649048, 0.295138895511627, 0.257575750350952, 
0.272727280855179, 0.273042917251587, 0.257260113954544, 0.20864899456501
), SQI_1900 = c(0.168244957923889, 0.158143937587738, 0.200757578015327, 
0.230744943022728, 0.242739900946617, 0.179924249649048, 0.147727280855179, 
0.130997478961945, 0.157196968793869, 0.139835849404335, 0.141729801893234, 
0.144886359572411, 0.139204546809196, 0.142676770687103, 0.147727280855179, 
0.148042932152748, 0.148989900946617, 0.151515156030655, 0.163510099053383, 
0.162247478961945, 0.187184348702431, 0.163825750350952, 0.167929291725159, 
0.196338385343552, 0.171401515603065, 0.181186869740486, 0.173611119389534, 
0.171085849404335, 0.163510099053383, 0.152777776122093, 0.153724744915962, 
0.158775255084038, 0.185606062412262, 0.167613640427589, 0.161931812763214, 
0.153093427419662, 0.196338385343552, 0.205492421984673, 0.172032833099365, 
0.202020213007927, 0.201388895511627, 0.210227265954018, 0.214646473526955, 
0.234848484396935, 0.206123739480972, 0.176136359572411, 0.190340906381607, 
0.194444432854652, 0.175820708274841, 0.163194447755814)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L))
```

I want to subset it to contain only the rows corresponding to maximum value across all columns containing "ZDR" in the column names, per Date. So for each unique date, find the maximum ZDR value across all "ZDR_*" columns, and then truncate the dataframe to just that row across all variables.

I wrote a very ugly base R function to do this:

```
trunc_func <- function(x){
  x$Date <- date(x$DateHour) 
  x_long <- melt(setDT(x), id.vars = c("DateHour"), variable.name = "Variable")
  x_long$Date <- date(x_long$DateHour)
  x_zdr <- x_long[str_detect(x_long$Variable, 'ZDR'),]
  x_remaining <- x_long[!str_detect(x_long$Variable, 'ZDR'),]
  x_zdr_max <- aggregate(x_zdr$value, by = list(x_zdr$Date), FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE)
  colnames(x_zdr_max) <- c("Date", "value")
  x_zdr_max2 <- merge(x_zdr_max, x_zdr, by = c("Date", "value"))
  x_remaining <- x_remaining[x_remaining$DateHour %in% x_zdr_max$DateHour, ]
  return(x)
}
```

But because there are multiple DateHour values per each variable, even though the truncation for zdr was correct, while merging with the remaining variables it fails since there are multiple rows per DateHour

I think there is some way to do this using a modified version of this:

```
df_trunc <- df %>%
    group_by(date(DateHour)) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), max, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But I am not sure how to go about it for partial string match in column names instead of across everything...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you had in mind

```
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(DateHour = with_tz(DateHour, "Asia/Dhaka"), # it looked like you were trying to put the data into BST, but it gave an error, hence me doing this
        Date = date(DateHour)) %>%
        group_by(Date) %>%
        mutate(max_zdr = max(across(starts_with("ZDR")))) %>%
        filter(if_any(starts_with("ZDR"), ~ .x == max_zdr))

# A tibble: 3 × 27
# Groups:   Date [3]
  ZDR_1100 ZDR_1500 ZDR_1700 ZDR_1900 DateHour            dBZ_1100 dBZ_1300
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2.90     4.29     5.25     3.26 2014-06-27 19:00:00    -4.43   -2.40 
2     3.25     5.42     6.04     3.87 2014-07-02 17:00:00    -1.10    0.775
3     4.42     5.68     5.98     3.96 2014-07-09 17:00:00    18.6    18.6  
# ℹ 20 more variables: dBZ_1500 <dbl>, dBZ_1700 <dbl>, dBZ_1900 <dbl>,
#   RhoHV_1100 <dbl>, RhoHV_1300 <dbl>, RhoHV_1500 <dbl>, RhoHV_1700 <dbl>,
#   RhoHV_1900 <dbl>, PhiDP_1100 <dbl>, PhiDP_1300 <dbl>, PhiDP_1500 <dbl>,
#   PhiDP_1700 <dbl>, PhiDP_1900 <dbl>, SQI_1100 <dbl>, SQI_1300 <dbl>,
#   SQI_1500 <dbl>, SQI_1700 <dbl>, SQI_1900 <dbl>, Date <date>, max_zdr <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that gives me exactly what I want. Except that it is still messy and uses a for loop. Any other solutions will be welcome.

```
df$Date <- date(df$DateHour)
# Find columns containing "ZDR"
zdr_columns <- grep(paste(c("ZDR", "Date"), collapse = "|"), colnames(df), value = TRUE)   

# Subset the dataframe to columns containing "ZDR" in their names
df_zdr <- df[,c(zdr_columns)]
df_zdr <- df_zdr[,!names(df_zdr) %in% "DateHour"]

# Subset remaining columns
df_remaining <- df[,!names(df) %in% "ZDR"]
df_remaining <- df_remaining[,!names(df_remaining) %in% "DateHour"]

# Find the row indices corresponding to the maximum ZDR values per Date
list_zdr <- split(df_zdr, f = df_zdr$Date)
list_remaining <- split(df_remaining, f = df_remaining$Date)
x <- list()


for(ii in 1:length(list_zdr)){
  zdr <- list_zdr[[ii]]
  zdr <- zdr[,!names(zdr) %in% "Date", drop = FALSE]
  n <- rownames(zdr)[which(zdr == max(zdr), arr.ind = TRUE)[ , 1]]
  
  zdr <- zdr[rownames(zdr) == n, ]
  
  rest <- list_remaining[[ii]]
  rest <- rest[rownames(rest) == n, ] 
  
  x[[ii]] <-  cbind(zdr, rest) 

  
}


x <- ldply(x, data.frame)

## x is the final output which is exactly what I want
```